# The element inside div don't get the gray backgroud when using absolute position

Tags: html, css

In the mobile version (width max 411px) when I create a navbar and I use absolute position when the dropdown active, why the background color don't cover all the element inside nav div?
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ShiningAss/pen/zYOqYJK) <<-- Here's the codepen version

I've using overflow hidden and still doesn't work

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.navbar-burger').click(function(){
        $('.inactive').toggleClass('active-nav');
        $('.navbar-burger').toggleClass('inactive');
        $('.navbar-close').toggleClass('close-navi');
        $('.header').toggleClass('border-bg');
    })
    $('.navbar-close').click(function(){
        $('.inactive').removeClass('active-nav');
        $('.navbar-burger').removeClass('inactive');
        $('.navbar-close').removeClass('close-navi');
        $('.header').removeClass('border-bg');
    })
})
```

```css
*{
    font-family: 'Open Sans Light', sans-serif;
    color: black;
}
body{
    margin: 25px 60px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.header{
    float: right;
    transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.navbar{
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.navbar ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}
.navbar ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 15px;
}
.navbar ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar ul li a:hover{
    color: #70BCFF;
}
.content{
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    padding: 70px 0px;
    cursor: default;
}
.welcome-message h1{
    font-size: 5.3em;
    margin: 0px;
}
.welcome-message h2{
    font-size: 2.15em;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: 60px;
    color: #707070;
}
.welcome-message h4{
    font-size: 1.0625em;
    color: #8D8D8D;
    margin-left: 4px;
}
.welcome-message p{
    font-size: 1.0625em;
    color: #8D8D8D;
    margin-left: 4px;
}
.expand-bio{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 0.3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .16);
    font-size: 1.0625em;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .16) 2px 7px 8px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.expand-bio:hover{
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .16) 2px 7px 14px;
}
.ava{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 100%;
}
.ava img{
    width: 70%;
    overflow: hidden;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
    margin: 0px;
}
.navbar-burger,.navbar-close{
    display: none;
}
.active a{
    color: #70BCFF;
}
/* Responsive Design */

@media only screen and (max-width: 1140px){
    body{
        font-size: 11px;
    }
}

/* iPad && iPad Pro && another tablet */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (max-height: 1366px){
    body{
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .content{
        grid-template-columns: 100%;
        grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
    }
    .ava{
        grid-area: 1/1;
        margin-bottom: 80px;
    }
    .welcome-message h1, .welcome-message h2, .welcome-message h4, .welcome-message p{
        text-align: center;
    }
    .welcome-message h4{
        margin-top: 15px;
    }
    .expand-bio{
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 26px;
    }
}

/* ================= */
@media only screen and (max-width: 412px){
    body{
        margin: 25px 10px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .navbar-burger{
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        right: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .close-navi{
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        right: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .navbar ul li{
        padding-bottom: 15px;
    }
    .inactive{
        display: none;
    }
    .active-nav{
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .header{
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .border-bg{
        background-color: #aaa;
    }
    .content{
        padding-top: 0px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>Ananda Vijaya</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b1643406ad.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar">
                <span class="navbar-burger"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></span>
                <span class="navbar-close"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Introduction</a></li>
                    <span class="inactive">
                        <li><a href="#">Finished Project List</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
                    </span>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="welcome-message">
                <h1>Hi There~</h1>
                <h2>This is the Place Where You Can Get to<br>Know Me Better</h2>
                <h4>Ananda Vijaya || Web Developer</h6>
                <p>I'm a Front-end Developer Who Currently a College Student<br>Majoring in Computer Science at Diponegoro University</p>
                <button class="expand-bio">My Complete Profile</button>
            </div>
            <div class="ava">
                <img src="ava.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I expect to have all the element (navbar menu) get the gray background color

Comment: In `.active-nav{
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
    }` remove the `position: absolute;`

Comment: I mean I want to make the navbar position fixed so the content doesn't have to go down when navbar is expanded. And I want to test if all the element go inside div so I give gray background color

Comment: ok, you so add to `.navbar` `position: fixed; width: 100%;`

Comment: it's not the width problem, but it's height problem (for mobile device) I want to all the navbar element get the grey background color